# Losing TextBoxFor value when using String.Format()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When using the following code `MyValue` is lost when the view model is sent to the controller.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.MyValue, new { @Value = String.Format("{0:N0}", Model.MyValue) })`

When I remove the String.Format() portion the value is passed correctly. Fyi, `MyValue` is a double.

How can I pass `MyValue` while retaining the formatting?

I've tried using a separate `HiddenFor` but this did not work. Also, I suspect if `MyValue` where a string instead of a double, the value would be passed. However, for now I'd rather keep it a double unless there is no easier way.

**Edit**

Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem. Here are some more details of the situation.

The following code works fine when I enter a number (e.g., 123456) without commas: The number is sent to the Save action of the controller and 123,456 is displayed in the Text Box. However, when when I click Save  again, and try to enter the number 123,456 with the comma, the Save action only receives a zero in the model parameter and a zero is displayed in the Text Box

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Model:

```
public class FormatTextBoxFor
{
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
    public class FormatTextBoxForController : Controller
    {           
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            FormatTextBoxFor model = new FormatTextBoxFor();
            return View(model);   
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FormatTextBoxFor model)
        {
            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
```

And the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "FormatTextBoxFor", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyDouble,  string.Format("{0:n0}", Model.MyDouble) )</p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" id="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I can only guess but what are the values for your double? For example if you do this with "0.333" it will show "0" and it will only return 0.0 - btw: there is a overload for `.TextBoxFor` where you can give the format-string - you should use this and I never had any problems using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833694(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: What you mean with "My value is lost"?

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz it returns 0.

Comment: Could you give an example input value to return zero when format?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, do you have an example of using that overload?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble sending foramtted TextBoxFor Value back to the controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875806/having-trouble-sending-foramtted-textboxfor-value-back-to-the-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyValue, new { @Value = Model.MyValue.ToString("N0") })
```