# Having trouble sending formatted TextBoxFor Value back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The following code works fine when I enter a number (e.g., 123456) without commas: the number is sent to the `Save` action of the controller and `123,456` is displayed in the textbox.

However, when when I click `Save` again, and try to enter the number `123,456` with the comma, the `Save` action only receives a zero in the model parameter and a zero is then displayed in the textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the model class:

```
public class FormatTextBoxFor
{
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
    public class FormatTextBoxForController : Controller
    {           
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            FormatTextBoxFor model = new FormatTextBoxFor();
            return View(model);   
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FormatTextBoxFor model)
        {
            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
```

And the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "FormatTextBoxFor", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyDouble,  string.Format("{0:n0}", Model.MyDouble) )</p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" id="submit" />
}
```

Comment: If I try to guess what the model binder is doing: `double.TryParse("12,434",out x)` won't work...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as you have shown - works fine in my project and the value is 123456 in the Save() method.

Comment: You're right. I tried it on another machine and it worked. Nevertheless, it refuses to work correctly on the original machine. I wonder what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on the server 123,456 is treated as text and not a number as you defined it in your model. On the server any value sent will will be mapped to the property of you model and parsed using default parser. You have to reformat the value before sending it to the server.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Any suggestions for reformatting

Comment: You can use jquery and intercept form submit event. During this event you can reformat the value by removing any extraneous characters. However I would recommend looking at 3rd party libraries such as Kendoui. In case of Kendoui you have numeric textbox that can be use instead of regular text box. There are other ways off handling this as well but the simplest are described above.

Comment: @Max, There is no need to reformat anything. The `DefaultModelBinder` will correclty bind `123,456` to a `double`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to be working on my machine running .Net framework 4.5.1 and MVC 5

Comment: @StephenMuecke, which framework are you targeting? For me, it works fine when the project is targeting .Net framework 4.

Comment: @navig8tr, I tested it with 4.5 and MVC 4

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Hmm, I just tried it on two machines. It worked on both machines when running Framework 4 and MVC 4, but it didn't work on either machine when running Framework 4.5 and MVC 5. Now I'll try it running 4.5 and MVC 4 as you did. Maybe it's an MVC 5 issue.

Comment: Guys it may be working in the over versions but in my opinion relying on framework to parse formatted values (unless it is explicitly documented) is waiting to get shut in the foot. Also it may be culture related. For example a way back we used xml reader. One day the program that used it simply stopped working. However when we run it locally it run find. So we decompiled dlls on both machines and behold the server dll had a different code in it even though both versions were exactly the same.

Comment: Her is a reference to an old blog about this issue http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/